# How do I run the same file with multiple shebang interpreter?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

So suppose I want to run some commands in bash and then say, octave. Is there any way to run the same file with two different commands? In the example below I want the first part to be run by bash and the second to be run by octave

```
#!/bin/bash
echo helloooo
#!/bin/octave
plot(1,2)
pause()
```

Comment: Haven't tried, but I guess all you need to do is create another executable with `#!/bin/octave` and run it in your `bash` script. Well not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one shebang possible at first line of a script.

Not sure of what you want to do here, but you can use the script's name to switch the script interpreter at run-time

Exemple `myscript.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case "${0##*.}" in
  # Switch script's interpreter based on script's name trailing .extension
  sh)
    echo helloooo
    ;;
  plot | octave | oct)
    octave < <(
        # Remove the Bash part of this script
        # by deleting lines up to what look like an octave shebang,
        # and send it to octave
        sed '1,/^#!.*[/[:space:]]\+octave$/d' "$0"
      )
    ;;
esac
exit # Bash stuffs ends here

# Octave stuffs starts here with fake octave shebang
#!/usr/bin/env octave
plot(1,2)
pause()
```

Then create a link to your script:

```sh
ln --symbolic --force myscript.sh myscript.oct
```

Running it as a Bash script:

```sh
./myscript.sh 
helloooo
```

Running as an Octave script:

```sh
./myscript.oct
...
```

Comment: A nice hack!  Not something I'd want to use at work though.

Comment: This hack is similar to what is used for bundling binary data (usually an executable or a self-extracting archive within a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

You could of course just by-pass the bash script altogether and do output in `octave` itself. It's a neater solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/octave
disp('hellooo')
plot(1,2)
pause()
```

Comment: This is ok if you want to always print "hellooo".

Comment: @LéaGris exactly. I wanted to be an example on what more I could do.